# Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) when scraping online data with VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, runtime-error

I created code that goes online to collect translations for a word list. It worked fine when I tested it on an individual entry, and it also worked fine for 23 entries when I added a loop. But then, subsequent translations started to come up empty, and eventually I got this run-time error appearing:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)

It appears in the line

```
IE.navigate "http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?word=" & EnglishTrans.Offset(0, 8).Value
```

A few other errors have also appeared in some of my attempts to run the code—unfortunately I did not write them down. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Screenshot[image: Screenshot1]

```
 Private Sub GetTranslation()

Dim EnglishTrans As Range
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Translation1 As String
Dim Translation2 As String
Dim Translation3 As String
Dim Translation4 As String
Dim Translation5 As String
Dim Translation6 As String
Dim IE As New internetExplorer

Set EnglishTrans = Range("d24")

Do Until EnglishTrans.Offset(0, 8) = ""

IE.navigate "http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?word=" & EnglishTrans.Offset(0, 8).Value

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document

On Error GoTo ErrHand

Translation1 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText)
Translation2 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText)
Translation3 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(8).innerText)
Translation4 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(11).innerText)
Translation5 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(14).innerText)
Translation6 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)

If Translation1 = "Traditional Script" Then
    EnglishTrans.Value = Translation6
Else
    EnglishTrans.Value = Translation1 & "|" & Translation2 & "|" & Translation3 & "|" & Translation4 & "|" & Translation5
End If

Set EnglishTrans = EnglishTrans.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

Exit Sub
ErrHand:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have found that upon restarting the computer it works again for a little while before the same thing happens all over again, and I have now reached ca. 50 entries. I have seen some posts about adding an exit from IE at the end of the code. So far I have tried IE.Quit, but that seems to stop the loop.

Comment: I forgot to mention; before they came up empty they started to repeat. And then, after I reset the program they started to came up empty. So first you get a long line of identical entries, and when you reset the program from the spot where the issue occurred they start coming up empty, as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to find a decent workaroud. The problem seems to be that too many instances of internet explorer are running. So I created a sub that kills all the IE instances:

```
Sub Kill_IE()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe", windowStyle, waitOnReturn

End Sub
```

I call this sub once every 29 entries (the issue now occurs slightly less frequently for unknown reasons), and that pretty much solves the problem—probably not the ideal solution, but I can set it and forget it.
I did not have any luck with the `IE.Quit` and `Set IE = Nothing` that I see some have suggested to fix this problem; it did not seem to mitigate the problem at all—that could certainly be due to poor implementation though. The other changes, such as the addition of the sub “SetPrefTrad,” are not related to this problem. The SetPrefTrad sub is just there to change the character set preference to traditional—Yellowbridge.com converts all characters to simplified by default.

```
Sub GetTranslation()

Dim IE As New internetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim EnglishTrans As Range
Dim Translation1 As String
Dim Translation2 As String
Dim Translation3 As String
Dim Translation4 As String
Dim Translation5 As String
Dim Translation6 As String
Dim i As Integer

Set EnglishTrans = Range("d2")


Call SetPrefTrad
i = 1


Do Until EnglishTrans.Offset(0, 8) = ""
If i = 30 Then
    Call Kill_IE
    i = 1
End If


IE.navigate "http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?word=" & EnglishTrans.Offset(0, 8).Value

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document

On Error GoTo ErrHand

Translation1 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText)
Translation2 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText)
Translation3 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(8).innerText)
Translation4 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(11).innerText)
Translation5 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(14).innerText)
Translation6 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)

If Translation1 = "Simplified Script" Or Translation1 = "See also" Then
    EnglishTrans.Value = Translation6
Else
    EnglishTrans.Value = Translation1 & "|" & Translation2 & "|" & Translation3 & "|" & Translation4 & "|" & Translation5
End If

Set EnglishTrans = EnglishTrans.Offset(1, 0)
i = i + 1

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

Loop

Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then Resume Next

End Sub

Sub SetPrefTrad()

Dim IE As New internetExplorer

IE.navigate "http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary-prefs.php?returnTo=%2Fchinese%2Fdictionary.php%3Fword%3D%25E5%2584%25AA"
IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim TradSimpOpt As Object

Set TradSimpOpt = IE.document.getElementById("characterMode")
TradSimpOpt.selectedIndex = "t"

Dim objInputs As Object
Dim ele As Object

Set objInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ele In objInputs
    If ele.Value Like "Save" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

End Sub

Sub Kill_IE()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe", windowStyle, waitOnReturn

Call SetPrefTrad

End Sub
```